# Difference between jquery $(...).hide() and $(...)._hide()

Tags: jquery

I ran across a weird call to jquery's `hide()` in code written by another programmer:

```
$('#eventStartTimePickerButton, #eventEndTimePickerButton')._hide();
```

What's the difference between `_hide()` and `hide()` in jQuery?

Comment: In what version do you see `$()._hide()`?

Comment: May be it is a custom function ?

Comment: Some sort of jQuery plugin added that method. Maybe jQuery UI? You could `console.log` both methods to see the difference.

Comment: Regarding the names of the selected elements it could be part of [jQuery UIs Widget Factory](https://api.jqueryui.com/jquery.widget/#method-_hide)

Comment: why don't you just type _hide in the search tab of chrome dev console (ctrl+shift+f or cmd+opt+f) and see which resources pop up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `_hide()` variant does not exist in jQuery. What is most likely the case is a custom extension of hide like

```
(function ( $ ) {

    $.fn._hide = function() {
        //custom implementation
        return this;
    };

}( jQuery ));
```

See [**How to Create a Basic Plugin**](https://learn.jquery.com/plugins/basic-plugin-creation/) for more details

**Update**

From the comment by `@Andreas`

This function exists as a method for base widgets in [**Widget Factories**](https://api.jqueryui.com/jquery.widget/#method-_hide)

So, if this is the case, then according to the source

```
this._hide( this.element, this.options.hide, function() {

  // Remove the element from the DOM when it's fully hidden.
  $( this ).remove();
});
```

the difference is the element is **removed** after the element is hidden(with any accompanied animations)

Comment: Your last edit does not show the source but an example. And there the part with `.remove()` is just a callback

Answer (score 0):

The function `_hide()` is not part of neither jQuery edge nor jQuery compat edge, it's either a function that's been defined elsewhere or that's added by a plugin.